# Facebook SDK for Mono for Android

Tags: c#, android, facebook, mono, xamarin.android

Can any one guide me how to integrate FB sdk for Mono platform for android in C#. I've tried implementing from some sample JAVA codes which are available but have not got any success. I would appreciate if some one can guide me step by step instructions to follow and sample code for Mono for android platform for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something to look at:

[Facebook Connect bindings for MonoDroid](http://mono-for-android.1047100.n5.nabble.com/Facebook-Connect-bindings-for-MonoDroid-td5111515.html)

And then there is :

[Facebook.MonoTouch](https://github.com/anujb/Facebook.MonoTouch)

I would suggest looking at the Facebook.MonoTouch first.

Or you could try using share intents:

```
public void share(String subject,String text) 
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionSend);

    intent.Type = "text/plain";
    intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraSubject, subject);
    intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraText, text);

    StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, GetString(R.string.share)));
}
```

Comment: Hi Matthew Thanks for the links you've shared. I hope this should make me integrate FB in MONO

Comment: Hi Matthew thanks for the snippet you have shared. But would you mind sharing a working code sample from FBApp integration perspective in an android app which is using above code snippet